# NSArrayController addObject throwing Exception

Tags: swift, swift5

When trying to add an object inside NSArrayController, exception is thrown. Using swift 5.0

```
@IBOutlet weak var  arrayController:        NSArrayController?


func addRule (_ rule: SelectRule) {
    self.arrayController?.addObject(rule)
}
```

Tried printing type of both rule and arrayController

```
        print(type(of: self.arrayController))
        print(type(of: rule))
```

Getting following output

```
@"Optional<NSArrayController>\r\n"
@"SelectRule\r\n"
```

i am able to print the contents of SelectRule as well (to ensure SelectRule) is nil.

```
@"{\r\n"
@"  \"enabled\" : true,\r\n"
@"  \"name\" : \"New rule\",\r\n"
@"  \"id\" : \"abcd\"\r\n"
@"}\r\n"
```

i also tried to catch the exception by altering the code

```
        do
        {
           try self.arrayController?.addObject(rule)
        }
        catch{
            print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
        }
```

Code is not reaching except block.

Any ways to avoid this issue ?

Comment: What kind of exception? By the way IBOutlets are supposed to be declared as implicit unwrapped optional. And you cannot catch errors which are not `thrown`

Comment: @RonakChaniyara https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsarraycontroller

Comment: @vadian i dont see any exception in console.. code is just halting there..

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information

Comment: Are you sure that your outlet is connected?